# how to minify css file containing @page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-4

css file for media='print' contains @page directive

```
.myreceipt {
    @page {
        visibility: hidden;
        margin: 0 15px;
    }

    @page {
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

ASP.NET MVC4 builtin minification does not minify it. Looking into source shows error

`(2390,5): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '@page'`

How to minify css containing @page in ASP.NET/Mono MVC4 application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid CSS syntax. Do it this way:

```
@page hide {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0 15px;
}

.myreceipt {
    page: hide
}
```

By the way, what you should be using is @media instead of @page

```
@media print {
    .myreceipt {
         visibility: hidden;
         margin: 0 15px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you css syntax produce exactly same result as code in my question ? You syntax does not specify `height: auto`

Comment: I changed css to use your @ media but in this case blank page appears. Maybe in original code visibility: hidden is ignored and shoud removed from your code ?

Comment: Yes, visibility is ignored in the original. What are you trying to do? showing the HTML and intended behavior will help us. As for the 'height: auto', you can add it back into the media.

Comment: I'm trying to refactor existing code which use this style to print receipts. I removed visibility and added height: auto to your second sample. Hope that this produces same results

Comment: If you are just re-factoring, try to remove the original instead of replacing it. Removing it should produce the same result since it's an invalid syntax.

Comment: I moved @page directive to top level and stanbdard header/footer disappeared. It looks like this directive is placed in wrong level and this was used to remove headers/footers

Comment: Maybe `height: auto` is used to prevent page breaks if printed to rolled paper ?

Comment: Don't know what it does. W3C CSS validator says that visibility and height are not allowed inside @page.

Comment: @page { visibility: hidden } removes header and footer in Chrome so it is very useful